# How do I link to a URL outside of my app using the Link component of react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey so i am trying to redirect to a external link like github instead of a path within the site,but I am having a problem.
Here Cards.js

```
import "./Cards.css";
import CardItem from "./CardItem";

function Cards() {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <h1>Check out my portfolios!</h1>
      <div className="cards__container">
        <div className="cards__wrapper">
          <ul className="cards__items">
            <CardItem
              src="images/img-9.jpg"
              text="Explore my dribbble profile where underlying are my illustrations and more"
              label="Adventure"
              path="https://www.google.com/"
            />
            <CardItem
              src="images/img-2.jpg"
              text="Travel through the Islands of Bali in a Private Cruise"
              label="Luxury"
              path="/services"
            />
          </ul>
          <ul className="cards__items">
            <CardItem
              src="images/img-3.jpg"
              text="Set Sail in the Atlantic Ocean visiting Uncharted Waters"
              label="Mystery"
              path="/services"
            />
            <CardItem
              src="images/img-4.jpg"
              text="Experience Football on Top of the Himilayan Mountains"
              label="Adventure"
              path="/products"
            />
            <CardItem
              src="images/img-8.jpg"
              text="Ride through the Sahara Desert on a guided camel tour"
              label="Adrenaline"
              path="/sign-up"
            />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cards;
```

So what i am trying to do instead of that path i am using href and a external link but its showing localhost/https:github.com like link instead of me redirected to the actual site.

also here is the
Carditeam.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function CardItem(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <li className="cards__item">
        <Link className="cards__item__link" to={props.path}>
          <figure className="cards__item__pic-wrap" data-category={props.label}>
            <img
              className="cards__item__img"
              alt="Travel Image"
              src={props.src}
            />
          </figure>
          <div className="cards__item__info">
            <h5 className="cards__item__text">{props.text}</h5>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}

export default CardItem;
```

So looking at these two codes what is that i can do to redirect on to a external link instead of a path
i know their is something to be change or twicked in the Carditeam.js for this so sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Link>` tag is used to route to views inside your application when using the `react-router`.

You need an `if` statement in `CardItem` so that if `props.path` is an external link you render an `<a class="cards__item__link" href={props.path}>`, if it isn't you can render `<Link className="cards__item__link" to={props.path}>`

Answer (score 0):

the component Link of `react-router-dom` is for navigation in your application.

You can use `<a className="cards__item__link" href={props.path}></a>`

But if this CardItem is for internal navigation,
You use `Link`

So, you can add 1 more props in `CardItem`
Ex: external

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function CardItem(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <li className="cards__item">
      { 
      
      props.external

      ?

      (
      <a className="cards__item__link" href="">
        <figure className="cards__item__pic-wrap" data-category="">
          <img className="cards__item__img" alt="Travel Image TRUE" src="" />
        </figure>
        <div className="cards__item__info">
          <h5 className="cards__item__text">"TRUE"</h5>
        </div>
      </a>
      )

      :

      (
      <h1 className="cards__item__link">
        <figure className="cards__item__pic-wrap" data-category="">
          <img className="cards__item__img" alt="Travel Image" src="" />
        </figure>
        <div className="cards__item__info">
          <h5 className="cards__item__text">"BLA"</h5>
        </div>
      </h1>
      )
      
      }
    </li>  
    </>
  );
}

export default CardItem;
```